# DataGrid MultiDataTrigger Bind to a ViewModel Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a View in MVVM WPF project. I have a DataGrid in the Page bound to a DataView (from a DataTable). What I need is to use MultiDataTrigger for the background color of the DataGrid Rows, that should be redefined by True value of the ViewModel Property:

```
 public bool IsAutorized
 {
     get { return _isAutorized; }
     set
     {
         _isAutorized = value;
         OnNotifyPropertyChanged("IsAutorized");
     }
 }
```

Whereas a True value is a property of DataRow. This is what I have now and the binding to the ViewModel property is not correct, when I set a breakpoint on the property get it is not "caught".

```
<Style.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="DataGridRow.IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCDAFF"/>
</Trigger>

<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>                                                                       
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsAutorized,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Page}}" Value="True" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=IsNotSpecific}"  Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCF4FF" />
</MultiDataTrigger>  </Style.Triggers>
```

The Binding issues are very confusing, I've tried googleing it but found nothing. Any Ideas hot to do it?

Thank you.

--
EDIT:

"IsNotSpecific" and "IsSelected" are both Colmns in the DataView, that is taken from the DataTable, a Strongly Typed DataSet table.

When a row is selected the field / column "IsSelected" is set to true and a certain color is triggerd. When the View property "IsAutorized" is set to true and the DataRow (from the DataTable) "IsNotSpecific" column are set to "True", a different color should be displayed.

Comment: Why did you write that RelativeSource? IsAutorized is obviously not a property of the Page.

Comment: @Clemens IsAutorized  is a property of the ViewModel. I simply try everything because I dont know what will work. How do I get to the VM properties?

Comment: Please, add more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsAutorized,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=DataGrid}}" Value="True" />
```

This condition would work if the IsAutorized property is in the Main ViewModel.

Comment: Sorry, doesnt work. The "IsAutorized" is not binded correctly and not called.

Comment: Which viewmodel has the "IsAutorized" property and ItemsSource of DataGrid?